# Regex pattern allows only digits after specific character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex pattern: `[^.][0-9a-zA-Z.\-_]*` which makes most of my required validations. Currently it only accepts + sign at the beginning, which is fine. But I need to add capability that it only accepts digits after + sign.

As an example:

**+1234** should be validated.

**+12ab** and **+ab123** shouldn't be validated.

What shall I add to the upper regular expression?

Comment: What are the requirements? Do you know that your regex allows literally any string with a very small exception?

Comment: Your requirements seem very unclear. Please provide some positive and negative examples.

Comment: Yes it can accept any string only if it doesn't start with '.' at the beginning. Other than, '-' and '_' characters are allowed to type and no restriction on string length,

Answer (score 1):

hi your regex pattern must be like :

for integer values  :

```
 ^(\+)?\d+$
```

for decimal values   :

```
(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+))
```

Comment: Thanks, updating the pattern as [^.|\+][0-9a-zA-Z.\-_]*|(^\+[0-9]*) solved my issue.